# How can I check if the value returned is null?

Tags: php

The code below works I am able to get the color of the car. Now, when the site was made professionally, some of the fields didn't get filled out. So, some of the fields either have a 0, have the word null, empty, or are empty. The one I am interested in is the color column. Some of the fields are empty.

```
Function getCarColor($cariD){
  the rest of my sql code
  $carColor = $ref['color'];
  return $carColor;
}
```

What I am stuck in is on how to check if they are empty and add a random text inside, just so that everything looks uniform.

This is my code

```
Function getCarColor($cariD){
  the rest of my sql code
  $carColorchk = $ref['color'];
  $carColor == is_null (('unspecified') ?: $carColorchk);
  return $carColor;
}
```

Please help. I will eat some extra tamales in your name on christmas dinner.

Comment: Did you tried  not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

you can use null coalesce operator if you are using **php 7**:

```
$carColor = $ref['color'] ?? 'nocolor';
```

or user below if php >=5.3 only

```
$carColor = $ref['color'] ?: 'nocolor';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. You can try the below one:

```
<?php
    if((!empty($your_value)) && ($your_value ! =0) && ($your_value !='')){
        //your Code
    }
?>
```

Comment: This works great too for the other problems. Wish I could mark your answer as best answer too.

Comment: @Divern: No problem. Glad that it helped you in someway.